# In scaffold ,error has been showed like " No value passed for parameter 'content' "- I have attached snap below

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, scaffold

I have already developed topBar and bottom bar separately.In ActivityScreen function line number 17,error has been occured.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After `)` in **line 17** you need to open braces `{ }` since the content of the scaffold will be created right there. Inside the braces you can add `Text()` , `Button()` and your UI, the first parameters you defined is the `Scaffold` are the configurations of the `bottomBar`, `topBarand` `backgroundColor`.

If you Ctrl + click on the Scaffold composable you will see its definition:

```
@Composable
fun Scaffold(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(),
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    snackbarHost: @Composable (SnackbarHostState) -> Unit = { SnackbarHost(it) },
    floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButtonPosition: FabPosition = FabPosition.End,
    isFloatingActionButtonDocked: Boolean = false,
    drawerContent: @Composable (ColumnScope.() -> Unit)? = null,
    drawerGesturesEnabled: Boolean = true,
    drawerShape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
    drawerElevation: Dp = DrawerDefaults.Elevation,
    drawerBackgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    drawerContentColor: Color = contentColorFor(drawerBackgroundColor),
    drawerScrimColor: Color = DrawerDefaults.scrimColor,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit ...
```

As you can see, all the parameters are optional except for the content. The content should be created, that's why you need to add the braces at the end of the composable.